# Spark custom receicer not get data

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, databricks, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using spark streaming to ingest my company's internal data source. I followed this tutorial to write a receiver: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html. But in Spark UI streaming tag, I always see 0 msgs coming in. Also I don't see any errors in driver logs. Really confused what goes wrong. (To connect to the internal data source,  need to create a `client`, then `listen()` will keep running to get the new msgs) I doubt is it because of the `listen` mode on the data source?

1. My Receiver

```
class MyReceiver(val clientId: String, val token: String, val env: String) extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) {

  def onStart() {
    new Thread("My Data Source") { override def run() { receive() } }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {  }

  private def receive() {
    while(!isStopped()) {
      try {
        val client = new Client(clientId, token, "STAGE")
        client.connect()
        client.listen(Client.Topic, new ClientMsgHandler() {
          override def process(event: ClientMsg): Unit = {
            val msg: String = event.getBody
            store(msg)
          }

          override def onException(event: ClientEvent): Unit = {
          }
        })
      } catch {
        case ce: java.net.ConnectException =>
          System.out.println("Could not connect")
        case t: Throwable =>
          System.out.println("Error receiving data")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

==================================================================

2. Create Stream

```
class MyStream(sc: SparkContext, sqlContext: SQLContext, cpDir: String) {

  def creatingFunc(): StreamingContext = {

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(3))

    // Set the active SQLContext so that we can access it statically within the foreachRDD
    SQLContext.setActiveSession(sqlContext)

    ssc.checkpoint(cpDir)

    val ClientId = <Myclientid>
    val Token = <Mytoken>
    val env = "STAGE"
    val stream = ssc.receiverStream(new MyReceiver(ClientId, Token, env))

    stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>  println("Here"+rdd.take(10).mkString(", "))

    }
    ssc
  }
}
```

==================================================================

3. Start Streaming

```
val checkpoint_dir = <my_checkpoint_dir>
val MyDataSourceStream = new MyStream(sc, sqlContext, checkpoint_dir)
val ssc = StreamingContext.getActiveOrCreate(checkpoint_dir, MyDataSourceStream.creatingFunc _)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Updates:
Since it's an internal source, I cannot share Client source code. But I've tested the connection. It works for below code and msg can be printed out correctly. You can think of `Client` as an external lib which has no connection issues.

```
val ClientId = <myclientid>
val Token = <mytoken>
val client = new EVClient(ClientId, Token, "STAGE")
client.connect()
client.listen(Client.Topic, new ClientMsgHandler() {
  override def onEvent(event: ClientMsg): Unit = {
    val res = event.getBody
    println(res)
  }
  override def onException(event: ClientEvent): Unit = {
  }
})
```

Comment: can you post your Client code ?

Comment: @Srinivas, pls see my updates

Comment: check your client code as its not reading & sending to spark. your spark code looks good.